# What is another way to say "the problems that led to it"?

Tags: phrase-requests

What is another way to say "the problems that led to it"? As in,

> Provides overview of the case, participants, background, and *problems
> that led to it*. Arguments for the plaintiff and defendant are thoroughly
> covered.

Comment: What sort or alternative are you looking for? What is wrong with the phrase in place?

Comment: 'Causes' is a hypernym that might suffice.

Comment: What kinds of cases and problems are being discussed?

Comment: Can you be more precise? I can see "problems that led to it" being used in various contexts. COVID was the problem that led to the development of a vaccine, but someone catching COVID was the problem that led to them dying from it.

Comment: Etiology/aetiology is the medical term; but you're looking for something specific to the legal world?

Comment: The sentence is not great, especially separating the word case and problems leading to it.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple possibility s -

- history
- underlying issues
- earlier failures
- preceding events

Comment: 'Underlying' is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

**Aggravating circumstances**.

> a circumstance relating to the commission of an act that increases the degree of liability or culpability

[MW-Law](https://www.merriam-webster.com/legal/aggravating%20circumstance)

This phrase is typically used in legal contexts, and is often defined in a particular jurisdiction ([example](https://nebraskalegislature.gov/laws/statutes.php?statute=29-2523)) with circumstances that are considered aggravating.

I'm biasing this on your use of the word "problems". If you are simply referring to the situation. A more neutral stance would include the realted **mitigating factors**.

> A mitigating factor, also called a mitigating circumstance or extenuating circumstance, is any fact or circumstance that lessens the defendant’s severity or culpability of a criminal offense.

[Cornell Law-Wix](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/mitigating_factor)

Combined this is often stated as *aggravating and mitigating circumstances*. You may substitute *factors* for *circumstances*.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest "the **facts** that led to it". Or "the **circumstances**".

Both fit with the rest of your summary and don't introduce a word in an entirely different register.

Answer (score 0):

I would use ether [root cause](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/root_cause) or root problem. If expecting multiple, as seems to be the case in this example, root problems.

Comment: Please add dictionary support to this good suggestion, jm.